# kotlinOptions.jvmTarget conflict with Gradle variants

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I used Kotlin Gradle plugin in my project and I set JVM target to 1.8. However, I found the published module -- the gradle variants don't respect that.

```
apply plugin: "kotlin"

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Here I want to set the target Java version as 1.8. And I checked the bytecodes of the build classes and it is Java 1.8.

```
gradle outgoingVariants

Attributes
    - org.gradle.category                 = library
    - org.gradle.dependency.bundling      = external
    - org.gradle.jvm.version              = 11
    ...
```

When I used the gradle task `outgoingVariants` it appears that the JVM version is the same as the one in my local (I uses Java 11).

So when this library was published into central repository, I can only use Java 11 in my main project to add this dependency, although the bytecode is actually 1.8.

Is there a way that I can keep the gradle variants respecting the Kotlin JVM target settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually set the attribute value as a workaround solution. Use something like this:

```
configurations["runtimeElements"].attributes {
    attribute(TargetJvmVersion.TARGET_JVM_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE, 8)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Alex. The code you provided could resolve my problem. I also created a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45335) in jetbrains and a [repo](https://github.com/PenghuaYu/gradle-test/) in gtihub to reproduce.